# Smartface 4.5 download image for offline usage

Tags: smartface.io

Can you share an working example that it downloads a png image to cache directory  and display it after app re-opened as offline usage?

Comment: could we capture current date and time from the application ?

Comment: you mean? `code` var now = new Date(); var day =  now.getDay() ;
var month =now.getMonth();  
var year=now.getFullYear(); `code`

Comment: Thank You Alex it's working well.